# Google Now service in my application

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, google-now, google-text-to-speech

I'm blocked with a service and google TTS.. Well, i want that a service starts in bg and when i say "ok google" or whatever i choose, starts the intent of text recognize. I created the service but now... What have i to do? I'm stuck. This is the service:

```
public class GnowService extends Service
{
    protected static AudioManager mAudioManager; 
    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    protected final Messenger mServerMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this));

    protected boolean mIsListening;
    protected volatile boolean mIsCountDownOn;
    private static boolean mIsStreamSolo;

    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING = 1;
    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                         RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                         this.getPackageName());
    }

    protected static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
    {
        private WeakReference<GnowService> mtarget;

        IncomingHandler(GnowService target)
        {
            mtarget = new WeakReference<GnowService>(target);
        }


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            final GnowService target = mtarget.get();

            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    {
                        // turn off beep sound  
                        if (!mIsStreamSolo)
                        {
                            mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                            mIsStreamSolo = true;
                        }
                    }
                     if (!target.mIsListening)
                     {
                         target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                         target.mIsListening = true;
                        //Log.d(TAG, "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                     }
                     break;

                 case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                    if (mIsStreamSolo)
                   {
                        mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                        mIsStreamSolo = false;
                   }
                      target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                      target.mIsListening = false;
                      //Log.d(TAG, "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                      break;
             }
       } 
    } 

    // Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around
    protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
    {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
            try
            {
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
                message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
        {
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        }
    }

    protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
        {
            // speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore
            if (mIsCountDownOn)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }               
            //Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech()
        {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
         }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error)
        {
            if (mIsCountDownOn)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
             mIsListening = false;
             Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
             try
             {
                    mServerMessenger.send(message);
             }
             catch (RemoteException e)
             {

             }
            //Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = true;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.start();

            }
            Log.d("", "onReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results)
        {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
        {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Have i to create something in my `MainActivity`? How can i "tell" to the app to recognize for example the words: "ok google"? to start the intent? Thanks
EDIT:

This is the part i inntegrated in the manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".mBootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GnowService"></service>
```

in my MainActivity i created the Broadcastreceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBootCompletedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction("com.dd.speech.GnowService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    };
```

First of all.. is so far correct? Or i'm in wrong? Then, the others points i don't know if i have understand and if i'm able to do it. Have you a sample part of code for that?

Answer (score 1):

In my answer propose solution the recognizer always listens. It just does not do anything until the key word is spoken. Let assume the app does not do anything until the user say "start end game" and do nothing again when the user say "stop end game".

1. Register for Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED in the manifest and create a BroadcastReceiver class to listen to this event and start the service. Your app has to launch at least one time for the receiver to receive this broadcast.
2. In your MainActivity start the service in onCreate. If you want to communicate with the server, then bind to the service in onStart and unbind in onStop.
3. In the service, create a flag private boolean mShouldProcessResult;
4. In onResults if the mShouldProcessResult flag is false just check if the results contains "start end game". If yes, give some indication to the user that the app will start processing his/her spoken words and set the mShouldProcessResult flag to true, else do nothing. If the mShouldProcessResult flag is true, process what ever the user spoke, this should include "stop end game".

Be aware that the battery life will be shorten considerably, in some case about half.

Comment: Will your idea prevent spoken words from going to the Internet (Google servers) before "start end game" is recognized (like "OK Google" works for Google Now)? If not, is it possible at all to accomplish that in any of the existing Android versions? Thanks +1.

Comment: Then you need to use Sphinx or offline Speech Recognizer which only is available from Jelly Bean up.

Comment: Thanks Hoan.  Isn't PocketSphinx available to all Android versions from 2.2 up? If so, you may be referring to some other "offline Speech Recognizer" that is only available from JellyBean up. Right? Do you have a specific such offline recognizer in mind? (i.e. can you recommend one?)

Comment: The offline available from JellyBean is the Google Speech Recognizer. However you have to turn off internet connection. So I think PocketSphinx is your option.